# How do I tell what angle is my hinge?

Tags: cabinets, hinges

On line it says there are both 110 and 120 degree hinges. I am trying to find information on my Blum hinge since it is faulty and I need a replacement.

I took a picture of my hinge. It says model number is 70T555 01 01 Blum Austria but online it says there are both 110 degree versions and 120 degree versions

[image]

So I understand what 70T555 and that is the model number, but what does the 01 01 stand for, and how do I find what angle is the hinge?

Comment: It was pretty easy to google the model number and find it is a 120 degree hinge. I do not know about the 01 01. It appeared as part of the model number in some of the search results....

Comment: @Jack I googled it as well but also found a 110 degree hinge, so I'm not too sure which part to buy

Comment: FWIW, I found only one ebay site that says it is 110 degree, all the others, there were 4 or 5 I checked, says they were 120. I would go with the majority. Unless shipping is outrageous, they don't cost all that much, for my 2 cents, get one of each if all you need is one. If you are replacing all of them, as long as they match your original configuration, whether it is full overlay, or half overlay, it won't matter if they are 110 or 120.